# Outlook Add-in Icon does not show up on Outlook Mac

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

We have an add-in on Outlook Desktop that runs for Outlook on Windows and Outlook on Mac.

On Mac I do not see the Add-in icon, instead, I see default icon that Outlook populates.

```
<IconUrl DefaultValue="../Images/forms_icon_25px.png"></IconUrl>
```

The size of the icon is 25px and it works fine on Outlook for Windows. OWA has no issues.

Answer (score 1):

Use explicit values in your manifest. So instead of `../Images/` you should use something like `"https://imgur.com/testimg.png"`